# Determining which field the polynomial $P(x)$ defines

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

It is easy to determine which field a quadratic polynomial defines, simply by computing the discriminant. What about cubic polynomials?

Which fields do $x^3-3x±1$ and $x^3-5x±1$ define?

I am aware the first set of polynomials not factor in the Finite Fields $F_2$, $F_5$, and $F_7$.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean by *a field defined by a polynomial*? If it is the splitting field $K(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, where $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are the zeros of the cubic in an algebraic closure of $K$ you need to tell us the base field $K$. If a polynomial $f(x)$ is irreducible in $K[x]$, $K$ some field, then we can also form the field $K[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$. But, again, you need to tell us what the base field $K$ is. Otherwise the question is meaningless. As you seem to have observed a polynomial with integer coefficients can be viewed over **any** field $K$.

Comment: My first comment probably sounded unnecessarily harsh. I do acknowledge that the phrase *field defined by a polynomial* is often used at least in the context of (characteristic two) finite fields. But in such a context the assumption $K=\Bbb{F}_2$ is implicitly made. Here there is no such context available, which is why I ask you to specify $K$.

Comment: For example, over $K=\Bbb{Q}$ the only sensible field *defined by $x^3-3x\pm1$ is $\Bbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/9))$, because that is the field generated by a root (and also the splitting field). Over $\Bbb{F}_2$ you would get $\Bbb{F}_8$, over $\Bbb{F}_5$ you would get $\Bbb{F}_{125}$ et cetera.

Comment: Can you give a link to a text where this phrase was used? Then we can trace it back to something and clear the fog :-)

Comment: The comment I upvoted is what I am asking. Can the same reasoning be applied to $x^3-5*x+-1$?